# Scipy: Sparse matrix is of wrong dimension?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to do:

```
scipy.sparse.dia_matrx(x, shape = (x.size, x.size))
```

but the resulting shape of the matrix is x.size x 1. Am i doing something wrong? Or did i miss something in the documentation?

It matters because I'm multiplying by dense matrices/vectors.

TIA

```
>>> t scipy.sparse.dia_matrix(x, shape = (x.size, x.size))
>>> t
<217766x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 217766 stored elements (217766 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
>>> t.shape
(217766, 1)
```

X is a 217766x1 Numpy Array

Comment: What is `x`?  Can you extend the example? (create `x`, print out the size of the generated matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` has shape `(N, 1)`, then I think you want:

```
 t = dia_matrix((x.T, 0), shape=(x.size, x.size))
```

If `x` has shape `(N,)` (i.e. it is a 1-d array), then the transpose of `x` in the above is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i attempt that it is complaining: ValueError: number of diagonals (217766) does not match the number of offsets (1)

Comment: Right--I reread your question and noticed that you said `x` has shape (N, 1).  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Looks like the code for this type of sparse matrix could use more error checking. The documentation is clear, but not adamant, that the 1st argument should be a tuple if it includes diagonal values. If it's an array, it just converts that to a sparse matrix, ignoring the shape argument.